# Error: Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'CalendarMode'

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Having some troubles getting my local copy of a website to work for the company I am working for currently. This is the code and errors accordingly.

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" CalendarMode="Month" PopupPosition="BottomLeft"
                TargetControlID="ManufacturedMonth" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="ValidateDate"
                ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="yyyy-MM" PopupButtonID="CalBtn2" runat="server">
                </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Error   57  Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'CalendarMode'.

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" CalendarMode="Month"  PopupPosition="BottomLeft" 
                                TargetControlID="ManufacturedMonth" ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="yyyy-MM" PopupButtonID="CalBtn2" runat="server"/>
                                <br /> </div>
```

Error   58  Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not have a public property named 'CalendarMode'.

Comment: There is no property `CalendarMode` in [CalenderExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Comment: Well it's working on the live website, with the same AjaxToolkit. I've basically just copied it straight from there to have a copy on my computer so in theory it should work...right?

Answer (score 0):

This error message indicates that in .NET class that is backing up this control does not have public CalendarMode property.
Please replace:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" PopupPosition="BottomLeft"
            TargetControlID="ManufacturedMonth" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="ValidateDate"
            ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="yyyy-MM" PopupButtonID="CalBtn2" runat="server">
            </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

and

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" 
                            TargetControlID="ManufacturedMonth" ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="yyyy-MM" PopupButtonID="CalBtn2" runat="server"/>
                            <br /> </div>
```

Comment: Yeah this wasn't helpful at all. It's working on the live website, I've literally just copied it down, with the AjaxToolkit folder aswell and suddenly it's not working. That's the issue. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I think someone modified (extended) CalendarExtender with that additional property, and you are missing this extension.

Comment: How is that possible if it's working on the live site and I am using the exact same AjaxToolKit? :s

Comment: But I am, I copied it straight from the live site.